# How do I find a kotlin annotation both on the param and property of a data class constructor?

Tags: kotlin

In the following code, only Apple can be found on the property, and Orange, Pear & Banana on the param. What if I want to be able to find Pear on both the property AND the param? It would be ridiculous to require the users of my library to have to remember to specify `@param:Pear @property:Pear` each time, as that's an implementation detail that's not exposed anywhere on Pear without reading the source - surely there is a cleaner way than this? Why don't annotations apply to *all* applicable targets?

```
import kotlin.reflect.full.findAnnotation
import kotlin.reflect.full.primaryConstructor
import kotlin.test.Test

@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class Orange

@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY)
annotation class Apple

@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY, AnnotationTarget.VALUE_PARAMETER)
annotation class Pear

@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.VALUE_PARAMETER)
annotation class Banana

data class Foo(
    @Orange
    @Apple
    @Banana
    @Pear
    val i: Int)

class AnnotationFun {

    @Test
    fun `can find annotations`() {
        val o1 = Foo::i.findAnnotation<Orange>()
        val a1 = Foo::i.findAnnotation<Apple>()
        val b1 = Foo::i.findAnnotation<Banana>()
        val p1 = Foo::i.findAnnotation<Pear>()
        println("$o1 $a1 $b1 $p1")
        
        val param = Foo::class.primaryConstructor!!.parameters[0]
        val o2 = param.findAnnotation<Orange>()
        val a2 = param.findAnnotation<Apple>()
        val b2 = param.findAnnotation<Banana>()
        val p2 = param.findAnnotation<Pear>()
        println("$o2 $a2 $b2 $p2")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you place an annotation at a location where its target is ambiguous, the compiler will select the target which appears first in this list ([documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets)):

1. Constructor parameter (`AnnotationTarget.VALUE_PARAMETER`)
2. Property (`AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY`)
3. Field (`AnnotationTarget.FIELD`)

You need to take this into account and design your annotation API accordingly. If your library is going to pick up annotations made on an instance's properties, restrict the associated annotation definitions to that target.

> What if I want to be able to find Pear on both the property AND the param?

As you suggested, the annotation target can also be specified at the annotation site, so to annotate both the property and the parameter you can annotate with `@Pear @property:Pear` or `@param:Pear @property:Pear`. In such a case you also need to add `@Repeatable` to the definition of `Pear`.

> surely there is a cleaner way than this? Why don't annotations apply to all applicable targets?

Ultimately the Kotlin team have made a design decision that each annotation usage applies to one target only. I think this makes most sense as it's the default: comparing to overloaded functions you would similarly only expect one to be called.

This is not restrictive to a library author as there is more than enough flexibility in how annotations can be defined to write a clean API for users.

Comment: Right, I understand the defaults without use-sites. Again, I think it's pretty hostile to end users of a library to have to understand the semantics of how an annotation is defined. So, say I need to use an annotation in both contexts within the library - what's a workaround without passing the burden down to library users?

Comment: You can either define a separate annotation or check all potential targets for annotations.

Comment: But that's the point - all potential targets do not have the annotation. Kotlin adds the annotation to the _first_ matching target, not _all_ matching targets.

Comment: And in my specific case, for the annotation to work it needs to be on both the param and property - this isn't "more than enough flexibility", it's very inflexible and restrictive.

Comment: It sounds like the only inflexible and restrictive thing here is the coding approach in your own project.

Comment: Wow Simon, you're bitter. I have a legitimate need to use the same annotation on params and properties. If you don't want to contribute to the discussion, please de-thread yourself.